# rails server does not start any server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am a complete Ruby on Rails newbie following the [railstutorial.org](http://www.railstutorial.org) 
I just installed rails 3.2.13, created a project with `rails new`.

However I could not started the server using the command:

```
rails server
```

It returns the `rails`command help message below (instead of WEBrick info) which does not mention the `server`command at all. So how can I start the server? Thanks

```
Usage:
rails new APP_PATH [options]
Options:
-r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                             # Default: /Users/nathanzylbersztejn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby
-b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
-m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
  [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
-G, [--skip-git]               # Skip Git ignores and keeps
-O, [--skip-active-record]     # Skip Active Record files
-S, [--skip-sprockets]         # Skip Sprockets files
-d, [--database=DATABASE]      # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                             # Default: sqlite3
-j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]  # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                             # Default: jquery
-J, [--skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
  [--dev]                    # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
  [--edge]                   # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
-T, [--skip-test-unit]         # Skip Test::Unit files
  [--old-style-hash]         # Force using old style hash (:foo => 'bar') on Ruby >= 1.9

Runtime options:
-f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
-p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
-q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output
-s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist

 Rails options:
-h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit
-v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
  The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
  directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

  You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
  'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
defaults values shown above in this help message.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the following:

```
./script/rails s
```

Comment: I had to call rails from the root of my app. I did not get that. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445088/cant-start-rails/27445881#). You can refer this for clear explanation of your problem.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27445881/3423992)