# Can't start Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

I updated Rails and Ruby:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
$ rails -v
Rails 4.1.8
```

Now when I execute `rails server` I get this:

```
$ rails server
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                   # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                      # Default: /Users/guilherme/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                           # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]               # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]             # Don't run bundle install
  { ... }
```

What I have to do to start Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not start the Rails server unless you're in your project directory.

Suppose if you're working on myapp project. You've to  move to that project directory on your command line and then run the Rails server.

Example: Assuming you didn't create the Rails app yet:

```
$> rails new myapp
$> cd myapp
```

Now start the Rails server with either of these two commands:

```
$> rails server
```

or:

```
$> rails s
```

Answer (score 1):

You should go to your Rails project directory first

Comment: Hi @eugui. If you've found this answer helpful please check the checkbox next to the upvote / downvote icons. This gives both you and shirakia reputation.

Comment: While this post does answer the question, it would be helpful to provide more details.  Your answer is in the low quality posts queue and in danger of deletion.

Comment: This provided the answer which the author required. The author understood in 1 min. Question's description was enough to answer. Details are written in another answer. So no need to modify this answer. Can be deleted if someone want.